# Create wrapper div around two other divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I add an div element around 2 (or more) div? What I think:

```js
$('div.list-price').each(function() {
  $(this).before('<div class="action-price">');
  $(this).next().after('</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-price">20000</div>
<div class="sell-price">10000</div>
```

I hoped that above code will do this:

```html
<div class="action-price">
  <div class="list-price">20000</div>
  <div class="sell-price">10000</div>
</div>
```

But:

```html
<div class="action-price"></div>
<div class="list-price">20000</div>
<div class="sell-price">10000</div>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: your before and after usages are invalid as these methods do not write text to the document content, they rather write _nodes_. so, the 1st ('before') inserts the auto-closing (bu jQuery itself) tag, and the second ('after') skips due to invalid markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of the elements as HTML code, but they are objects. You can't add the starting and ending tag separately, because they are not complete elements.

Add the new element, and move the existing divs inside it:

```
$('div.list-price').each(function() {
  var newDiv = $('<div/>').addClass('action-price');
  $(this).before(newDiv);
  var next = $(this).next();
  newDiv.append(this).append(next);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/eFXbN/1/

Comment: Thx Guffa, you are right, but one line is missing inside each():
$(this).parent('div').addClass('action-price');

Comment: @riskogab: I have already added that, and also a link to a demo. :)

Comment: @Blowsie : How can you ONLY do it on the first 2 divs?

Answer (score 8):

Try using the wrapAll function:

```
$('.list-price, .sell-price').wrapAll('<div class="action-price" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice approach to this is to do the following.

```
$("div.list-price").each(function(){
     $(this).nextUntil("div.list-price").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='action-price'></div>");
});
```

Its simple and readable, probably the way the jQuery devs intended it to be written.

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = ... // the 1st element
$rest = ... // other elements, may be just the second one
$first.wrap('<div class="wrapper"/>').parent().append($rest)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to revese your last line to:

$rest.wrap('').parent().append($first);